Labelling contour lines with OGR_STYLE
I'm trying to add labels to DEM contour lines.
I'm working with GDAL 3.6.2. , which I installed using Anaconda . I have some DEM data from USGS which I wrote as a contour map to a KML file using:
gdal_contour small.tif /home/ubuntu/node/geotools/contour.kml -i 3.0 -f KML -a ELEVATION

When I open contour.kml in vim, I can see that its made up of features like:
<Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#contour">
        <SimpleData name="ID">39</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ELEVATION">525</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
    <LineString><coordinates>-89.2626638689733,46.1525006611575 -89.262663868958,46.1525469572921 -89.2627325352002,46.152622208059 -89.2628251277396,46.1526266807347 -89.2629177202847,46.1526141000471 -89.2629982621728,46.1525469573863 -89.2629982621882,46.1525006612516</coordinates></LineString>
</Placemark>

Clearly there is a style component available , but I'm not sure how to work with it to add elevation labels or custom colours. My suspicion is that OGR_STYLE is used to do things like this (https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/835)(https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#ogr-style    ), but I can't find any examples. How can this be done?

Here is an example on how you can do this by adding styles. I have tested this snippet on Google Earth.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>KmlFile</name>
    <StyleMap id="msn-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#sn-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#sh-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="sh-pushpin">
        <BalloonStyle>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <!-- Yellow -->
            <color>ffff00ff</color> 
            <width>1</width>
            <gx:physicalWidth>1</gx:physicalWidth>
            <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="sn-pushpin">
        <BalloonStyle>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <!-- Red -->
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>1</width>
            <gx:physicalWidth>1</gx:physicalWidth>
            <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>My Path Name</name>
        <styleUrl>#msn-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
            -89.2626638689733,46.1525006611575 -89.262663868958,46.1525469572921 -89.2627325352002,46.152622208059 -89.2628251277396,46.1526266807347 -89.2629177202847,46.1526141000471 -89.2629982621728,46.1525469573863 -89.2629982621882,46.1525006612516
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>


Minimum working example might be the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
     >

<Document>
  <name>LineStyle.kml</name>
  <Style id="linestyleExample">
    <LineStyle>
      <color>7f0000ff</color>
      <width>4</width>
      <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>
  <Placemark>
    <name>LineText Value</name>
    <styleUrl>#linestyleExample</styleUrl>
    <LineString>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
            -89.2626638689733,46.1525006611575 -89.262663868958,46.1525469572921 -89.2627325352002,46.152622208059 -89.2628251277396,46.1526266807347 -89.2629177202847,46.1526141000471 -89.2629982621728,46.1525469573863 -89.2629982621882,46.1525006612516
            </coordinates>
    </LineString>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>



Thank you, this is definitely getting closer. Ideally I was hoping to have the info visible along the contour without having to click on a popup. this doesn't seem to work when I upload the KML to mymaps

On google earth you don't need to click on the line to get the name. However the text may dissapear on some zoom levels.

Maybe it's worth moving to https://earth.google.com/ ? It can import KML as well

Its a possibility, Its just that I have multiple other kml files which I usually add to mymaps. Anyway , your system does work for google Earth.
